# Jquery Qtip multi ajax load form fail javascript control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, qtip2

Hello I whant to call this:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=editar_domicilio]').each(function(){
    $(this).qtip({
        //id: 'modal', // Since we're only creating one modal, give it an ID so we can style it
        content: {
            // Set the text to an image HTML string with the correct src URL to the loading image you want to use
            text: 'Cargando...',
            ajax: {
                url: './abm_info_contacto_modificar.php?iddomicilio=' + $(this).attr('rel') + '&idpersona=' + $('#idpersona').val(),
                once: false // Re-fetch the content each time I'm shown
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Modificar Domicilio',
                button: true
            }
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center', // ...at the center of the viewport
            at: 'center',
            target: $(window)
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click', // Show it on click...
            solo: true, // ...and hide all other tooltips...
            modal: true // ...and make it modal
        },
        hide: function() { $('#formulario_domicilio').remove(); },
        style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'
    })
}).click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });// Make sure it doesn't follow the link when we click it
```

from a table like this

```
<table align='center'><thead><tr><th></th><th id='DOMICILIO'>DOMICILIO</th><th id='FECHA'>FECHA</th><th id='LOCALIDAD'>LOCALIDAD</th><th id='TIPO'>TIPO</th><th id='ACTUAL'>ACTUAL</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id='tr10'><td><a href="editar_domicilio?var=10" title="Modificar" rel="10"><img src='../../tema_blanco/modificar.png' border='0' style='margin:0px 1px 0px 1px;'></a>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;5 N° 1 PISO 23 DEPTO 23&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;12/06/2012&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;MISIONES - COL. ALBERDI&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;COMERCIAL&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;NO&nbsp;</td></tr><tr id='tr3'><td><a href="editar_domicilio?var=3" title="Modificar" rel="3"><img src='../../tema_blanco/modificar.png' border='0' style='margin:0px 1px 0px 1px;'></a>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;666 N° 67 PISO 68 DEPTO 69&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;11/06/2012&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;CATAMARCA - LAS JUNTAS&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;PARTICULAR&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;NO&nbsp;</td></tr><tr id='tr4'><td><a href="editar_domicilio?var=4" title="Modificar" rel="4"><img src='../../tema_blanco/modificar.png' border='0' style='margin:0px 1px 0px 1px;'></a>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;5 N° 5&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;11/06/2012&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;MISIONES - COL. ALBERDI&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;PARTICULAR&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;NO&nbsp;</td></tr><tr id='tr5'><td><a href="editar_domicilio?var=5" title="Modificar" rel="5"><img src='../../tema_blanco/modificar.png' border='0' style='margin:0px 1px 0px 1px;'></a>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;5 N° 11 PISO 22 DEPTO 22&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;11/06/2012&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;BUENOS AIRES - J. B. ALBERDI&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;PARTICULAR&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;NO&nbsp;</td></tr></table>
```

the problem occurs in the form called width ajax, i call once and work perfect but if i close it and try to open from another link on the table the javascript that controls the inputs (included in the form width ajax) fails, "I Think" the previus form is still present in the dom, i hope you can understandme because my english suck! thank you very much.

Comment: Could you please provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ? This will help a little bit :) I'll try then to help you.

Comment: sorry, I'm new at this and did not know you have answered, finally i solved I solved with this: events:{
    hide: function(event, api) {
     $('.ui-tooltip-content').empty()
    }    }
   },
thanks anyway, sorry for my english.